# Multisite & Views on Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, multi-sites

In a multi-site configuration in Drupal 8 with (N) cloned (carbon copies) sites, is there any way an individual site can pull the content from other sites in the network into a View on its instance?

For example, in a view on Default, pull content from site 1, site 2, and/or site n.

Comment: Have a look at Content Sync module, the module allows content to be exported and imported like Drupal Core Configuration Management System.

Comment: Youcll need to extend it a little bit to allow export a from one site and to import into another site.